# What type of sparse vector should I use?

Tags: c++, data-structures, containers, sparse-matrix

**Data**

I have `N` different (sorted) vectors of indices (`std::vector<unsigned int>`). The indices are in the range [0; L-1]. Here are two rules of thumbs about this data:

- Only about 0.1% to 10% of possible index are present anywhere
- If an index is found in a given vector, then it will likely be found multiple times again in other vectors.

Hence a possible data set with `N=10` vectors and with `L = 200` could be

```
{45, 110, 119, 145, 170}
{9, 45, 110, 145, 178, 170}
{45, 145}
{45, 178, 183}
{45, 53, 110, 170}
{9, 119, 123, 179}
{9, 45, 119, 130, 131, 170, 190, 199}
{9, 45, 110, 170, 199}
{31, 45, 145}
{9, 178, 183}
```

**Goal**

I would like to compute the frequencies of every index. I would do something like

```
std::vector<double> computeFrequencies(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>& data)
{
    assert(data.size() == N);

    std::vector<double> frequencies(L);
    for (unsigned Ni = 0 ; Ni < N ; Ni++)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0 ; i < data[Ni].size() ; i++)
        {
            assert(data[Ni][i] < L)
            frequencies[data[Ni][i]]++;
        }
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0 ; i < L; i++)
    {
        frequencies[i] /= (double) N;
    }

    return(frequencies);    
}
```

I will then loop again through the object returned by the function `computeFrequencies` only once.

```
for (unsigned i = 0 ; i < L; i++)
{
    foo(frequencies[i]);
}
```

**Question**

The object `frequencies` contains a lot fo zeros and I should hence be using a sparse vector instead. I don't have much understanding of sparse matrices though. What type of sparse vector should I use?

I am considering using `boost::numeric::ublas::coordinate_matrix<double><double>` because as I loop through all `N` vectors, I would constantly be adding new non-zeros values and I think a coordinate matrix would be good for dealing with that. Note that generally speaking, for this function, I am more worried about RAM usage than about computational time.

Comment: Since your OS will likely not back any allocation with actual memory pages before you actually write to them (default for Linux at least), I'd say don't worry about it. If you want to allocate a terrabyte and only write to a few gigabytes, and what you write to will actually fit in memory, then don't worry about the virtual memory size. It costs nothing unless you actually use it.

Comment: If you're using only a few GB of memory it's really not worth fussing, as the trade-off between memory and compute is often very real. Very compact structures tend to be more CPU intensive. Very sparse structures can be very easy to access. `std::map` is one alternative if you have an extremely sparse structure, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like a sparse vector representation is a good fit for your problem.

To accomplish your task as you describe it:

1. Merge your sorted vectors into a single sorted vector.  How to do an efficient K-way merge pops up here every now and then: [merging N sorted files using K way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935884/merging-n-sorted-files-using-k-way-merge)
2. Iterate through the new vector and count the number of duplicates of each entry (easy since they'll all be together) to get your frequencies and `foo` them as you go.

You can even do both steps at the same time, entirely avoiding the need to copy the data into a new structure.